# How do I solve this overloading error (c1) condition?

Tags: c++

How can I use the operator keyword or any other way to solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Counter {
    Counter(int count_) : count(count_) {}
    int count;
};

int main() {
    Counter c{0};
    // Error: could not convert 'c' from 'Counter' to 'bool'
    if (c) { std::cout << "true\n"; } 
    else { std::cout << "false\n"; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) but code instead.

Comment: It is not clear what you are expecting `if(c1)` to do. What does it mean to check if a counter is true or false?

Comment: OP: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider reading through the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) help pages before submitting your next question. It will increase the probability of getting a good answer (or one at all) to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a [*user-defined conversion function*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) to `bool`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Counter {
    Counter(int count_) : count(count_) {}

    // User-defined conversion to bool
    operator bool() const {
        // Arbitrary predicate: return false if 0, true otherwise.
        return count != 0;
    }

    int count;
};

int main() {
    Counter c{0};
    if (c) { std::cout << "true\n"; } else { std::cout << "false\n"; }  // false
    c.count++;
    if (c) { std::cout << "true\n"; } else { std::cout << "false\n"; }  // true
}
```

Note, however, that it is quite semantically unclear what is meant by checking whether a counter is "true" or "false" - this answer only covers *how* you may implement such a user-defined conversion function, although it is arguably not a semantically sound approach for this particular class. Instead, a user may want to know, for a given counter class, e.g.:

- whether it is zero (`bool isZero() const { return count == 0; }`),
- whether it is saturated to some maximum value.